# How to make an application deployed to google cloud app engine available to certain white-listed IPs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an application deployed to an app engine service. I have many services under the same app engine. How can I make the application available to certain white-listed IPs? In other words, I want this application to accept requests from certain IPs and deny all other request? 
Can we do this by writing some configurations in app.yaml file? 
Note: I just want to apply the rule to one service only so that other services will not be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying this kind of restriction at a service level is, at the moment, not possible.

The best option would be to deploy the services you want to protect on a different project, and use the [App Engine firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls) there.